# Why there are two "files" apps

Tags: files

Somehow I've got two similar "Files" app installed. Since it is translated, I can't even identify the name to purge it. How do I leave Phanteon Files only?

[image]

They seems quite similar, but for sure is not the same app.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Pantheon-files by elementary LLC has a light-grey folder icon with a 'home' symbol on top of it. To uninstall its competitor ('Arquivos' app with a  blue locker icon):

1. Go to `AppCenter` > `Installed` tab.
2. Scroll until you find `Arquivos` app with a blue locker icon.
3. Click it and hit `Uninstall` button.

Comment: Once there if the icons are the same, you can identify the one that it is from elementary when you click on it, it is written *elementary LLC*. The other one looks like it is Nautilus file manager used in Ubuntu Gnome.